# Parameter type not assignable when storing func in dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a func which takes one parameter of Type T and returns one value.

I want to store it in a dictionary, like so:

```
Dictionary<CustomerMilestones, Func<string, string>> coll = new Dictionary<CustomerMilestones, Func<string, string>>();

string Indicator = coll[CustomerMilestones.Ordered100Products].Invoke(customerId.ToString());

coll.Add(CustomerMilestones.Ordered100Products, Execute(Indicator);
```

Execute is a method which takes a string but also returns a string. On the last line, the error is as follows:

Argument type string is not assignable to parameter type Func.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be *calling* Execute - you just need to provide it as a method group:

```
coll.Add(CustomerMilestones.Ordered100Products, Execute);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you should be passing in the Execute method, not the results of the execute's invocation.

coll.Add(CustomerMilestones.Ordered100Products, Execute);